Approximation function for MLP and LSTM
I have total of 6300 samples, 5800 of which are training data, and 500 of which are testing data. We compare the performance of LSTM and multilayer perceptron (MLP) with one hidden layer in terms of training process, prediction accuracy and learning ability.
we can observe that RMS error of
LSTM is 3.47998, which is less than the MLP of 5.02391. It means LSTM is better than MLP in prediction. Learning ability analysis can be demonstrated by the curve comparison of forecast and observation TEC. We presented the prediction of six days from 2001/3/1 to 2001/3/6 in below Figure. It can be observed that the TEC curve forecasted by  LSTM is closely fit for the observed TEC curve which is  the ground truth, while there is considerable gap between the curve forecasted by MLP and the ground truth. It indicates MLP is inferior to LSTM in TEC forecast. Nevertheless, the tendency of forecast is right.

My question is: is it possible to find/define appropriate distribution function for both LSTM and MLP based on the above curves in figure?

Update:
Consider the above case is Case1.
And there is another two variations of TEC curve below:
Case2: From 2015/6/18-2015/6/23, variation of TEC is very complicated. Beside the periodic variation, there are strong disturbance during one period. On this occasion, LSTM can capture the cyclic changes, and therefore give a better forecast, however, MLP is totally wrong with an inverse direction. Comparing to MLP, LSTM have the advantage of predicting long sequence data due to the memory cell. LSTM can learn the long dependencies of sequential data, not only the very past moment, but also a segment of history is taken into account. While MLP does not utilize history information, so it may fail in case of turbulence of TEC.
Case3:
In case TEC varies suddenly, such as the case illustrated in Fig. 6, where the peaks of observed TEC in
the five past days are large, while it dramatically becomes low in the next day. In this situation, RMS error becomes significant.


Above, we discussed three cases of TEC changes, where LSTM all behave better than MLP. The achievement
owes to the special design of LSTM, so that it can learn long dependences of sequential data. Thus, the interaction and relationship of the elements of sequential data can be learnt, and the better representation of input data can be obtained.
My question is: what can we say by seeing curves of above three cases for both LSTM and MLP? is it possible to define appropriate distribution function for both LSTM and MLP based on the above curves in figures of three cases? Is there any mathematical representation through distribution possible for three cases?

What do you mean when you say “find the distribution function”?

@Sycorax I want to know is there any possible distribution based on the curve like normal or uniform or Gaussiun etc distribution.

Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/649392/2921, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/129454/8560, https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/46008/1794.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Based on your answer to Sycorax I infer that you want to look at the distribution of residuals and compare the two empirical distributions of the residuals (MLP vs LSTM). For comparison you could look at e.g. "approximate/empirical" first order stochastic dominance of the residuals.
Another approach could be to plot a histograms of the paired differences of absolute residuals |residual_MLP(x_i)|-|residual_LSTM(x_i)|. If the histogram has more weight on positive differences then the MLP is "more often more wrong"

Is it possible to represent mathematical representation of distribution of residuals and empirical distributions of the residuals?

Would you explain your motivation why you use distribution of residuals?

I am considering residuals because the smaller the residuals, the better the fit (imagine a model having only residuals which are zero...). You could also consider the distribution of observations P(y,t) this will lead you to probabilistic models and typically  maximum likelihood estimation

|residial_MLP(x_i)| it should be residual?

Yes, the absolute value of the residual at value x_i

I have another two variations of this curve. Is the answer is same as like case1? Or would you please update the answer based on this update. Please look up my updated question.

Yes it is still the same answer

Okay thanks for your confirmation. One final question question how to define distribution functions and their ranges for both LSTM and MLP?

I would go with the empirical distribution function in the case of looking at the residuals https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function . In the case of looking at the distribution of the observed values in e.g. maximum likelihood estimation it is up to you to come up with a suitable distribution which you assume ...
